# How to use MPUT in PSFTP to put the file with permission 777

Tags: linux, sftp, psftp

I don't want to use chmod 777 *.xml so how I can use MPUT to put the file with permission 777?
Now when I do not use chmod 777 *.xml then default put file with permission 0664.

This is my script

```
dir
lcd E:\Inbound
cd /interface/incoming
mput *.xml
chmod 777 *.xml
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, psftp does not support setting permissions of files while uploading them. So setting the permissions after upload using `chmod` command is the only way.

On *nix, psftp preserves permissions of source files.